# Did Muhammad write down the Quran

Tags: quran

After researching and youtube videos about the Quran,  Did Muhammad write down the Quran or did Abu Bakr, Umar, or Uthman have it compiled?

Comment: Nabi SAW was taught the Quran orally through the Angel Jibra’eel. However there are conflicts over who compiled the Quran. Some sources like Wikipedia say it was Abu Bakr as he was the first caliph and he ordered others to find and compile the scriptures. But Wikipedia isn’t the most reliable source

Comment: @Music Man Ender - So, you believe in all of those people who make videos full of lies about Islam?

Comment: @Ren maybe this knowledge is new to him so he asked people to get clarification

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No.

### Illiteracy

It is said

> Those who follow the messenger, the `Prophet who can neither read nor write,` whom they will find described in the Torah and the Gospel (which are) with them. He will enjoin on them that which is right and forbid them that which is wrong. He will make lawful for them all good things and prohibit for them only the foul; and he will relieve them of their burden and the fetters that they used to wear. Then those who believe in him, and honour him, and help him, and follow the light which is sent down with him: they are the successful. **[ [Pickthall’s Translation of the Qur’an](https://quranx.com/7.157) ]**

Hence the Messenger could not have written the Qur’an if he is illiterate.

### The First Compilation of the Qur’an

It is said in this Hadith:

> Narrated Zaid bin Thabit:Abu Bakr sent for me owing to the large number of casualties in the battle of Al-Yamama, while Umar was sitting with him. Abu Bakr said (to me), Umar has come to my and said, 'A great number of Qaris of the Holy Qur'an were killed on the day of the battle of Al-Yamama, and `I am afraid that the casualties among the Qaris of the Qur'an may increase on other battle-fields whereby a large part of the Qur'an may be lost.` Therefore I consider it advisable that you (Abu Bakr) should have the Qur'an collected.' `I said, 'How dare I do something which Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) did not do?'` Umar said, By Allah, it is something beneficial.' Umar kept on pressing me for that till Allah opened my chest for that for which He had opened the chest of Umar and I had in that matter, the same opinion as Umar had." Abu Bakr then said to me (Zaid), "You are a wise young man and we do not have any suspicion about you, and you used to write the Divine Inspiration for Allah's Messenger (ﷺ). So you should search for the fragmentary scripts of the Qur'an and collect it (in one Book)." Zaid further said: By Allah, if Abu Bakr had ordered me to shift a mountain among the mountains from one place to another it would not have been heavier for me than this ordering me to collect the Qur'an. Then I said (to Umar and Abu Bakr), "How can you do something which Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) did not do?" Abu Bakr said, "By Allah, it is something beneficial." Zaid added: So he (Abu Bakr) kept on pressing me for that until Allah opened my chest for that for which He had opened the chests of Abu Bakr and Umar, and I had in that matter, the same opinion as theirs. So I started compiling the Qur'an by collecting it from the leafless stalks of the date-palm tree and from the pieces of leather and hides and from the stones, and from the chests of men (who had memorized the Qur'an). I found the last verses of Tawbah: ("Verily there has come unto you an Apostle (Muhammad) from amongst yourselves--' (9.128-129) ) from Khuzaima or Abi Khuzaima and I added to it the rest of the Sura. The manuscripts of the Qur'an remained with Abu Bakr till Allah took him unto Him. Then it remained with Umar till Allah took him unto Him, and then with Hafsa bint Umar. **[ [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7191) ]**

Abu bakr says the messenger never collected the Qur’an into one book, and based on Umar’s worry about the death of Qaris leading to the loss of a large part of the Qur’an we can safely conclude the whole Qur’an had not been written down by the Messenger, even if he was literate. Which he wasn’t.